# How do I get the username written in the installation log of any software installation?

Tags: java, ubuntu, logging, installation

I want to obtain the name of the user who has installed a software, to be written in the installation log. Is it at all possible? Please throw some light.

Comment: In what programming language? In what operating system?

Comment: java and ubuntu linux

Comment: I don't understand the reason of my question being down-voted.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use java.lang.Runtime.exec() to call the linux command 'whoami'. that will give you the current user.

many linux distributions also have environment variables preset with the current user that you could try to read with System.getProperty(), but the whoami is probably a bit more robust.

I just noticed there is also a Java System Property user.name that is supposed to hold the user account name, try reading that with System.getProperty()